# AutoMapper registration in Unity DI

Tags: c#, unity-container, automapper, registration

I'm not that familiar with Unity or StructureMap.  How do you convert the following StructureMap registration sample into Unity registration syntax?

```
    public class ConfigurationRegistry : Registry
    {
        public ConfigurationRegistry()
        {
            ForRequestedType<ConfigurationStore>()
                .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton)
                .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<ConfigurationStore>()
                .CtorDependency<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>>().Is(expr => expr.ConstructedBy(MapperRegistry.AllMappers));

            ForRequestedType<IConfigurationProvider>()
                .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<ConfigurationStore>());

            ForRequestedType<IConfiguration>()
                .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<ConfigurationStore>());

            ForRequestedType<IMappingEngine>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<MappingEngine>();

            ForRequestedType<ITypeMapFactory>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<TypeMapFactory>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should put your solution as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.  Let me know if I missed something.

```
Container
 .RegisterType<ConfigurationStore, ConfigurationStore>
                              (
                                 new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()
                               , new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ITypeMapFactory)
                               , MapperRegistry.AllMappers())
                              )
 .RegisterType<IConfigurationProvider, ConfigurationStore>()
 .RegisterType<IConfiguration, ConfigurationStore>()
 .RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>()
 .RegisterType<ITypeMapFactory, TypeMapFactory>();
```